# How to parametrise a surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces, spherical-coordinates, parametrization

How would one parametrise the surface:$$x^2+2y^2+z^2=1$$

I was thinking that you would need to use spherical coordinates, $x=r \sin\theta \cos\phi$, $y=r \sin\theta \sin\phi$ and $z=r\cos\theta$, although, I'm not sure how this works in regards to this specific surface because of the coefficient of the $y$-component.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: So, $x=\sin\theta\cos\phi,\sqrt2y=\sin\theta\sin\phi, z=\cos\theta $

Comment: Hint: Use the transformation $w=\sqrt{2}y$ so that $w^2=2y^2$, parametrize the sphere, and then transform it back.

Comment: Have you noted that your surface is an ellipsoid ?

Comment: @JeanMarie would that change the parametrisation?

Comment: It can give you ideas about other parametrizations (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ellipsoid.html) (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/205915)

Comment: I understand how the parametrisation works now, I think it was more the coefficient of 2 out of the front of the $y$ term that was confusing me.

Answer (score 0):

To parametrise this surface you could simply write this as :
$\left ( x, y, \sqrt{1-x^2-2y^2} \right)$

This is the easiest way ! And from here you can do your Gradient or Jacobian easely. Of course there is some better way to parametrise, but you should plot and see if you can project on the (x,y) plane or something.